# In Python, how do I change/insert code of a method by other objects/functions/methods

Tags: python, methods

I am not new to python but I am far from being an expert (or intermediate). Right now, I play around with objects and their behavior (like setattr, monkey-patch, etc.). During this, I stumbled upon a problem where I do not have any idea on how this might work.

Imagine following code:

```
class MyCalculator():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def addition(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def substraction(self, a, b):
        return a - b

import inspect

class Changing():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def listUserMethods(self, myObject):
        object_names = [object_name for object_name in inspect.getmembers(myObject) if (inspect.ismethod(object_name[1]))]
        return object_names

    def setMethodAttribute(self, myMethod):
        pass


if __name__=="__main__":
    myCalc = MyCalculator()
    change = Changing()
```

Now, I would like that setMethodAttribute() will change the code of the method I provide itself. Like, inserting a print() statement before the rest of the original method is executed. E.g. printing the input parameter before executing the addition, etc.
In my case, this does not need to be done during runtime (even if this is very interesting to know). I could imagine, that using inheritance or something similar could be a way. Perhaps somebody has a great idea?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How would you like it to work? Something like `change.setMethodAttribute(myCalc.addition)`? Do you want to write the code for the "printing" inside `Changing.setMethodAttribute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer really depends what you are after.

### Wrapping a method of a class (before runtime)

This is very typical use case of *decorators* (the `@something` above a function definition).

```py
def with_printing(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Before calling method")
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("After calling method")
        return ret

    return wrapper


class MyCalculator:
    @with_printing
    def addition(self, a, b):
        print("calling addition")
        return a + b
```

If you want to keep the docstring of the original method, you would use the [`functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

#### Example output

```py
mycalc = MyCalculator()
print(mycalc.addition(2, 3))
```

would print

```
Before calling method
calling addition
After calling method
5
```

### Wrapping a method of an object instance (runtime)

Here is one implementation which changes the method of an object. Note that this changes the method of an *instance*  and not every instance of that class.

```py
class MyCalculator:
    def addition(self, a, b):
        print("calling addition")
        return a + b


class Changing:
    def set_method_attribute(self, obj, method_name):

        method = getattr(obj, method_name)

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Before calling method")
            ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
            print("After calling method")
            return ret

        setattr(obj, method_name, wrapper)
```

#### Example usage

```py
# Create two calculator objects for testing
mycalc = MyCalculator()
mycalc2 = MyCalculator()

change = Changing()

# Before change
print(mycalc.addition(2, 3))
print("----")

# After change
change.set_method_attribute(mycalc, "addition")
print(mycalc.addition(2, 3))
print("----")

# The another calculator object remains unchanged
print(mycalc2.addition(2, 3))
```

will print

```
calling addition
5
----
Before calling method
calling addition
After calling method
5
----
calling addition
5
```

Comment: Thank you! That made a lot of sense. I watched some tutorials (from Corey Schafer) some longer time ago. Totally forgot the idea behind decorators. I played with your input and got different things and constellations to work as I expect. I might not have yet understood everything, but it is getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated some of the code in a new way. Would you mind taking a look on it and telling me if this is a "good" way?

```
import inspect

class InBetween():
    def __init__(self):
        object_names = [object_name for object_name in inspect.getmembers(self) if (inspect.ismethod(object_name[1]) and (object_name[0] != 'with_print'))]
    
        for name in object_names:
            method = getattr(self, name[0])
            wrapper = self.with_print(method)          
            setattr(self, name[0], wrapper)

    def with_print(self, method):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                print("before")
                ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
                print("after")

                return ret

        return wrapper

class MyCalculator(InBetween):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    def addition(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def substraction(self, a, b):
        return a - b

    def multiply(self, a, b):
        return a * b

if __name__=="__main__":
    myCalc = MyCalculator()
    print(myCalc.addition(2,5))
    print(myCalc.multiply(2,5))
```

The basic idea is, that every class wich will inherit "InBetween" can add via super() the wrapper to each method. Without doing this manually in the script. My next idea is, to replace the print statements by logging etc. At the end, if I call the parent "**init**" infromation will be easily logged, and if not, "nothing" happens.

Love to hear other opinions on that!

Thank you all!